# How does a processor calculate bigger than its register value?

Tags: cpu-registers

So far I learned that a processor has registers, for 32 bit processor
they are 32 bits, for 64 bit they are 64 bits. So can someone explain
what happens if I give to the processor a larger value than its register
size? How is the calculation performed?

Comment: Can you give larger value ?

Comment: for example how 32 bit processor would calculate 55340232221128654845 x 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends.

Assuming x86 for the sake of discussion, 64-bit integers can still be handled "natively" on a 32-bit architecture. In this case, the program often uses a pair of 32-bit registers to hold the 64-bit value. For example, the value `0xDEADBEEF2B84F00D` might be stored in the `EDX:EAX` register pair:

```
eax = 0x2B84F00D
edx = 0xDEADBEEF
```

The CPU actually *expects* 64-bit numbers in this format in some cases ([IDIV](http://faydoc.tripod.com/cpu/idiv.htm), for example).

Math operations are done in multiple instructions.  For example, a 64-bit add on a 32-bit x86 CPU is done with an `add` of the lower DWORDs, and then an [`adc`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Arithmetic#Carry_Arithmetic_Instructions) of the upper DWORDs, which takes into account the carry flag from the first addition.

---

For even bigger integers, an [arbitrary-precision arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) (or "big int") library is used. Here, a dynamically-sized array of bytes is used to represent the integer, with additional information (like the number of bits used).  [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) is a popular choice.

Mathematical operations on big integers are done iteratively, probably in native word-size values at-a-time. For the gory details, I suggest you have a look through the source code of one of these open-source libraries.

---

The key to all of this, is that numeric operations are carried out in manageable pieces, and combined to produce the final result.

Comment: I could ramble on, but I think you should check out the GMP source code, and/or compile some code that does 64-bit arithmetic, for a 32-bit architecture, and look at the resulting assembly.

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart thanxxx for your helpful answer. here goes my vote!