# How ALU actually does if we need to compute power of 2 (say 2 to the power 32) in a 32-bit system,is it possible?

Tags: processor, alu

How ALU actually does if we need to compute power of 2 (2ˆ32) in a 32-bit system,is it possible? In simple terms, say I have to compute power with a given base,then if the result of computation is greater than the number of bits that the computer can handle at a time (known as word),I am confused as I belong to high level programming only and curious to know about it.

Comment: Two 32-bit registers are often used for 64-bit numbers. Larger than that, a "Bit Int" library is often used. There is a ton of information out there about this, you just need to do some research and reading.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart thanks for your answer. Is it for 32-bit architecture (Two 32-bit registers)?

Comment: Yes. For example x86 (before x86-64 came around).  The general purpose registers are all 32 bits.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart ohhh yes,thanxxxx again. I studied a bit in college,but my specification was software engineering,so these things are left to electronics department or so... :) but they go hand in hand with one another...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does a processor calculate bigger than its register value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17205968/how-does-a-processor-calculate-bigger-than-its-register-value)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart How computer stores a float value,for example if I have to store 2147483648 as a float,then it would be something like 2.147483648*10ˆ9 which is converted into binary equivalent? I have been trying to learn it for sometime now but not able to wrap it yet.